# speeding up Solve or NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of equations which I am trying to solve.

```
Solve[ms^2 == -2 (M^2 - (6 (k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 + 
       c + 2 m5^2) && 
   ma^2 == -2 (M^2 - (2 (3 k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 - 
       c + 2 m5^2) && 
   mp^2 == 2 b m (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
        m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)))^(-1) && 
   v == Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
     m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)), {k1, k2, c, b}] /. {ms -> 500, 
  ma -> 980, v -> 92, m -> 5.5, M -> 364, m5 -> 0}
```

But wolfram was trying to solve it more than 3 hours. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to get anything useful from `NSolve` it will require that there be as many equations as unknowns. Right now it is too few (4 vs 6). Also the substitutions should happen before calling `Solve`, in order for there to be much chance it will run to completion.

Comment: Do you know `M5` and `m5` are different variables.? I notice you don't give value to `M5` when you are done.

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but let M5 and m5 are same variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to convert to algebraic expressions, do the numeric substitutions, then find a Groebner basis that in effect "triangularizes" it so that the variables of interest can be solved in terms of the remaining parameters.

For this purpose I show a direct code below. One could explicitly change the radicals into new variables, with corresponding relations, but I do not go that far. `GroebnerBasis` will figure it out anyway, and the only drawback is once it removes its "internal" variables from the output, things involving the radicals might look weird.

```
  eqns = Apply[List, 
    ms^2 == -2 (M^2 - (6 (k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 + 
         c + 2 m5^2) && 
     ma^2 == -2 (M^2 - (2 (3 k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 - 
         c + 2 m5^2) && 
     mp^2 == 2 b m (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
          m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)))^(-1) && 
     v == Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
       m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2))] /. {ms -> 500, ma -> 980, v -> 92, 
        m -> 11/2, M -> 364, m5 -> 0};
    exprs = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]
    vars = Variables[exprs]

Timing[
 gbrat = GroebnerBasis[exprs, {k1, k2, c, b}, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions];]

(* Out[71]= {0.742745, Null} *)
```

The result is on the long side.

```
In[72]:= gbrat

(* Out[72]= {-11 b + 92 mp^2, 
 1269701225750632387225583616 + 16 c^5 + 
  38331760226742917136384 M5^2 + 289305037335035904 M5^4 - 
  4791470028342864642048 mp^2 - 72326259333758976 M5^2 mp^2 - 
  23391518267959296 mp^4 - 1263973681152 M5^2 mp^4 - 
  19079424 M5^4 mp^4 - 96 M5^6 mp^4 + 
  c^4 (12599680 + 64 M5^2 - 8 mp^2) + 
  c^3 (3868798402560 + 41918976 M5^2 + 64 M5^4 - 5239872 mp^2 - 
     16 M5^2 mp^2 - 11 mp^4) + 
  c^2 (582821073209589760 + 9921096966144 M5^2 + 33439232 M5^4 - 
     1240137120768 mp^2 - 8359808 M5^2 mp^2 - 4247368 mp^4 - 
     72 M5^2 mp^4) + 
  c (43262715370708774420480 + 1016778629212143616 M5^2 + 
     5490532483072 M5^4 - 127097328651517952 mp^2 - 
     1372633120768 M5^2 mp^2 - 546197270528 mp^4 - 
     19079424 M5^2 mp^4 - 144 M5^4 mp^4), 
 9582940056685729284096 + 16 c^4 + 144652518667517952 M5^2 - 
  36163129666879488 mp^2 - 176545090176 mp^4 - 6874800 M5^2 mp^4 - 
  44 M5^4 mp^4 + c^3 (10479744 + 32 M5^2 - 8 mp^2) + 
  c^2 (2480274241536 + 16719616 M5^2 - 4179904 mp^2 - 11 mp^4) + 
  c (254194657303035904 + 2745266241536 M5^2 - 686316560384 mp^2 - 
     2789912 mp^4 - 50 M5^2 mp^4) + (500000 M5^4 mp^4 - 8 M5^6 mp^4)/(
  132496 + c + 2 M5^2), 
 9582940056685729284096 + 16 c^4 + 289305037335035904 M5^2 + 
  2183500161024 M5^4 - 36163129666879488 mp^2 - 
  545875040256 M5^2 mp^2 - 176545090176 mp^4 - 9539712 M5^2 mp^4 - 
  144 M5^4 mp^4 - (96 M5^6 mp^4)/(132496 + c) + 
  c^3 (10479744 + 64 M5^2 - 8 mp^2) + 
  c^2 (2480274241536 + 33439232 M5^2 + 64 M5^4 - 4179904 mp^2 - 
     16 M5^2 mp^2 - 11 mp^4) + 
  c (254194657303035904 + 5490532483072 M5^2 + 24959488 M5^4 - 
     686316560384 mp^2 - 6239872 M5^2 mp^2 - 2789912 mp^4 - 
     72 M5^2 mp^4), 
 3117801746841600 + 29507389184 c - 87392 c^2 - c^3 + 
  4232 k2 mp^4, -6936898224442368 - 87155868800 c - 130156 c^2 + 
  c^3 + 6348 k1 mp^4, -29703370839766117917696000000000000 + 
  520066650864685777821696000000 M5^2 + 
  13622605280123027498139648 M5^4 - 238099500614170484736 M5^6 - 
  1931758864590848 M5^8 + 17181784576 M5^10 - 67712 M5^12 + 
  c^4 (-49593750000000 + 2116000000 M5^2 - 
     25392 M5^4) + (-1953125000000000 M5^8 + 93750000000 M5^10 - 
   1500000 M5^12 + 8 M5^14)/(k1 + k2) + 
  112091575744800288000000000000 mp^2 - 
  3654574303540812288000000 M5^2 mp^2 + 
  3757441485177747456 M5^4 mp^2 + 841797996443136 M5^6 mp^2 - 
  5416892288 M5^8 mp^2 + 16928 M5^10 mp^2 + 
  547220816619750000000000 mp^4 + 3467897167974000000 M5^2 mp^4 - 
  551724374390688 M5^4 mp^4 + 1122415272 M5^6 mp^4 + 
  125902 M5^8 mp^4 + 
  c^3 (-32483112750000000000 + 1220633644000000 M5^2 - 
     9754353728 M5^4 - 76176 M5^6 + 24796875000000 mp^2 - 
     1058000000 M5^2 mp^2 + 12696 M5^4 mp^2) + 
  c^2 (-7687881291636000000000000 + 241642470943136000000 M5^2 - 
     409170245317632 M5^4 - 37685045888 M5^6 - 16928 M5^8 + 
     12956069625000000000 mp^2 - 519729804000000 M5^2 mp^2 + 
     5311007648 M5^4 mp^2 + 12696 M5^6 mp^2 + 34095703125000 mp^4 - 
     1454750000 M5^2 mp^4 + 17457 M5^4 mp^4) + 
  c (-787904142851402304000000000000 + 
     19435155129766498304000000 M5^2 + 160779731080178020352 M5^4 - 
     5577633215976448 M5^6 - 10833784576 M5^8 + 33856 M5^10 + 
     2127313244784000000000000 mp^2 - 
     77871254610784000000 M5^2 mp^2 + 540357461329408 M5^4 mp^2 + 
     6538338432 M5^6 mp^2 - 16928 M5^8 mp^2 + 
     8647637390625000000 mp^4 - 168524455750000 M5^2 mp^4 - 
     4003347156 M5^4 mp^4 + 96807 M5^6 mp^4), -1 + 
  92/((11 b)/(4 (132496 + c + 2 M5^2)) + Sqrt[(132496 + c + 2 M5^2)/(
   k1 + k2)]/Sqrt[2]), 
 220407621303771773534208 + 368 c^4 + 3327007929352912896 M5^2 - 
  831751982338228224 mp^2 + 46000000 M5^4 mp^2 - 736 M5^6 mp^2 - 
  4060537074048 mp^4 - 158120400 M5^2 mp^4 - 1012 M5^4 mp^4 + 
  c^3 (241034112 + 736 M5^2 - 184 mp^2) + 
  Sqrt[(132496 + c + 2 M5^2)/(
   k1 + k2)] (-250000 Sqrt[2] M5^4 mp^2 + 4 Sqrt[2] M5^6 mp^2) + 
  c^2 (57046307555328 + 384551168 M5^2 - 96137792 mp^2 - 253 mp^4) + 
  c (5846477117969825792 + 63141123555328 M5^2 - 
     15785280888832 mp^2 - 64167976 mp^4 - 1150 M5^2 mp^4)} *)
```

The point is one can now "back substitute" to get solutions. The first polynomial implies `b = 92/11*mp^2`, the second one gives `c` as a quintic in the parameters, etc.

Comment: It is very interesting answer! Thank you! It would be interesting to know is it posible to do for more complicated problem?  For example if I try to find a numerical calculation of a integral equation with parameters without FindRoot.

Comment: For example, I know how to solve: Veffd2i[M_?NumberQ, m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
 4 + NIntegrate[-((2 E^(-((m + Sqrt[4 + (l + M)^2])/T)) l^2)/((1 + 
          E^(-((m + Sqrt[(l + M)^2 + 4])/T))) T Sqrt[
         4 + (l + M)^2])), {l, -100, 100}, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; if I use FindRoot: Veffd2i2[m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
 M /. FindRoot[Veffd2i[M, m, T] == 0, {M, 0}];  Veffd2i2[1, -2]

Comment: I see no way to extending a method using polynomial algebra to handle root-finding of what amount to "black-box" functions that use e.g. quadrature. Methods using the likes of `FindRoot` or perhaps path-tracking via `NDSolve`, are the ways I know for how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to get numerical solution. you will need to specify all the parameters.
Choosing random values for `M5` and `mp`,

```
ms = 500; ma = 980; v = 92; m = 5.5; M = 364; m5 = 0; M5 = 10; mp = 10;

Eq1 = ms^2 == -2 (M^2 - (6 (k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 + c + 2 m5^2);
Eq2 = ma^2 == -2 (M^2 - (2 (3 k1 + k2) b^2 m^2)/(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)^2 - c + 2 m5^2);
Eq3 = mp^2 == 2 b m (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
      m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)))^(-1);
Eq4 = v == Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 M5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 M5^2));

NSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4}, {k1, k2, c, b}]
```

> {{k1 -> 1.60642*10^8, k2 -> -1.60642*10^8, c -> -257496., 
>     b -> 836.364}, {k1 -> 254.123, k2 -> -224.074, c -> -132671., 
>     b -> 836.364}, {k1 -> 0.13213, k2 -> -0.116479, c -> -132492., 
>     b -> 836.364}, {k1 -> 0.128457, k2 -> -0.113241, c -> -132500., 
>     b -> 836.364}}